# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CONFIG' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, config

The project created by CRA.

utils/config.js

```
   CONFIG={
    test:'test
   }
```

Then I imported at my src/index.js(which is root of project)

```
    <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact>
                        <MainContainer title={'Welcome to something'} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/dummy' exact>
                        <DummyContainer />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/pop/:topicId' exact>
                        <Popup />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/app' exact>
                        <App />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Provider>,
```

import 'utils/config';

I can access CONFIG from my component which is called from src/index.js

but error occurred that cannot access to CONFIG.

Is there anyway to put CONFIG in very first state?

THANK you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you exported it correctly. It should be either default or named export.
try changes below

utils/config.js

```
export default {
  test:'test'
}
```

src/index.js(which is the root of the project)

```
import config from 'utils/config'
```

now you can use your `config` object as you want

Comment: Well... 
Actually I want to use 'test' from child component which is called from src/index.js.
thank you anyway!